# What Ruby libraries support validation of Relax NG compact syntax?

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-parsing, schema, relaxng

What Ruby libraries support XML validation with Relax NG compact syntax?

I've tried Nokogiri so far, with no success. It only supports `.rng` files, not `.rnc` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any. It might be simplest to just convert your RELAX NG compact schema to the XML syntax with [Trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html).

Comment: I actually just found this and converted it. I'm having some difficulties with Nokogiri hanging when trying to validate the file though...

Answer (score 1):

This site looks like it might be what you're looking for:

https://github.com/sshaw/ruby-jing

It seems to wrap java code, but you can use ruby and the other claim is better error messages, which is always a good thing. Nothing worse than cryptic errors.